# How to create wiki-family on MediaWiki-Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, mediawiki

Are there any roles to manage or create multiple wikis? I have checked [Manual:Wiki family](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family) and understand the normal way of creating multiple wiki in a MediaWiki.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share what I got in addition to the [manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family).

Beside of multiple domains/subdomain you can get also **multiple path** for multiple wikis. Each will stand with different [configuration setup](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings) by adding the [*action path*](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgActionPaths) at the end line on each of your setting files as shown:

```
# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.

$wgArticlePath = "/map/$1";

$actions = array( 'edit', 'watch', 'unwatch', 'delete','revert', 'rollback',
  'protect', 'unprotect', 'markpatrolled', 'render', 'submit', 'history', 
  'purge', 'info' );

foreach ( $actions as $action ) {
  $wgActionPaths[$action] = "$wgArticlePath/$action";
}

$wgActionPaths['view'] = "$wgArticlePath";
```

Change the `map` variable to your path on each of the setting files then *place them under the folders named exactly follow to your path*.

So you can modify the code in the [LocalSettings.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family#Giant_switch_statement) similar as below:

```
<?php
// Include common settings to all wikis before this line (eg. database configuration)

    $paths = explode('/' , $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if($paths[2] === NULL) {$path = 'map';} else {$path = $paths[1];} 

    switch ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) {

        case 'wiki.tophyips.info':
                require_once "settings/$path/tophyips.php";
                break;

        case 'wiki.hyipscript.info':
                require_once "settings/$path/hyipscript.php";
                break;

        case 'wiki.hyipmonitors.info':
                require_once "settings/$path/hyipmonitors.php";
                break;

        default:
                header( 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' );
                echo 'This wiki is not available. Check configuration.';
                exit( 0 );

    }
```

Change the `map` variable on `$path = 'map';` to one of *your default path* of your choice from all the paths you put on the setting files above.

You may check the result of the configuration above on my [*wiki family page*](http://wiki.hyip.world/featured).

Comment: Yes, that is the normal solution in LocalSettings.php.

Comment: Nope. If you consider multiple path as Multi Path Installation (MW_INSTALL_PATH) then it is normal in [LocalSettings.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family#Giant_switch_statement).

Answer (score 1):

The [`mediawiki::wiki`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-vagrant/blob/master/puppet/modules/mediawiki/manifests/wiki.pp) module is used for creating wikis. Some roles that use it are [`commons`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-vagrant/blob/master/puppet/modules/role/manifests/commons.pp) and [`private`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-vagrant/blob/master/puppet/modules/role/manifests/private.pp) (there are surely more). If you just want to create a wiki without any extra configuration, you can just write `mediawiki::wiki{<wikiname>:}` and put it in `puppet/modules/role/manifests/my_role.pp` (inside a role block - see other role files for the format) and then you can enable/disable via `vagrant roles`.